# Flooding network interface with high traffic

Tags: linux, networking

I want to test my network interface capability about how much traffic it can handle. Can someone suggest me some of the tools to generate this much traffic. Moreover is there any other tools which we can use to benchmark network interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of tools out there that can do this. My personal favorite is iperf. It's free, easy, and can be ran on multiple platforms. However from my previous testing, I would try to stick either Windows <--> Windows or UNIX <--> UNIX because I got some odd numbers when I went from Windows <--> UNIX.